# GHC.Generics for default methods of sum types

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I want to use `GHC.Generics` to create default implementations of a class for all objects of the form `data X s  = X0 s | X1 O1 (X s) | X2 O2 (X s) (X s) | ...`.

Specifically I want the following:

```
class C (a :: * -> *) where
  cmap :: Applicative m =>
         (s -> m (a s')) -> ((a s) -> m (a s')) -> a s -> m (a s')
```

So that for example in the `Expr` type that follows:

```
data BEOp = EAdd | ESub | EMul | EDiv deriving (Generic, Eq)
data UEOp = EId deriving (Generic, Eq)
data Expr s = BinExpr BEOp (Expr s) (Expr s)
  | UnExpr UEOp (Expr s)
  | NExpr s deriving (Eq, Generic)
```

GHC will derive a default implementation of typeclass `C` that is equivalent to:

```
instance C Expr where
  cmap _ f (BinExpr o q q') = BinExpr o <$> f q <*> f q'
  cmap _ f (UnExpr o q) = UnExpr o <$> f q
  cmap f _ (NExpr s) = f s
```